# Where has my debugging information gone? Xcode 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, debugging, debug-symbols

Im trying out some iPhone scroll view tests, but when i load the view, the app just blows up.

I get no debugging information in Xcode, no EXC_BAD_ACCESS, no errors, just

`[Session started at 2010-07-16 10:35:21 +0100.]`
and
`Debugging terminated` in the bottom of the debugger window.

I have set `Generate Debug Symbols` in the target preferences to ENABLED, Debug Information Format is DWARF with dSYM.

How can i debug this problem with no errors?

This is the code, but im more concerned about where my debug info has gone

```
- (void)loadView {
UIScrollView *s = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

NSArray *a = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" 
                                     owner:self options:nil];

UIView *v = [a objectAtIndex:0];

[s setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400,500)];
[s addSubview:v];
[[self view] addSubview:s];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Debug" configuration of the project, and actually run with the debugger attached, i.e. CMD-Y or CMD-ALT-ENTER.